# Writing a script to repeat an Update query using an incrementing variable

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have table a:

```
a.si
a.p
a.pnsi
```

si is a unique id, p is a double, pnsi is null

I'd like to run an update query on pnsi using this subquery with variable n:

```
(SELECT si FROM a as y WHERE y.si = a.si + n AND y.p > a.p)
```

I'd like to be able to run this query on incrementing values of n from 1 to 100,000, each time only on the remaining records where pnsi is still null.

The query has two criteria:
1. That the si value selected (y.si) as a.pnsi is greater than a.si
2. That y.p is greater than a.p

The purpose of this is to reduce processing time, since this procedure is going to be run on a table of over a million records and most of the time, the correct solution can be found with a very small n value. By running it this way, Access will evaluate n = 1, 2 ... (ascending), resulting in very few records where n will increment all the way up to 100,000.

What I'm in need of is a script to increment through the values of n to repeat the update query n times on remaining null records. **The script needs to send the current value of the n variable to the Update query (y.si = a.si + n).** The loop stops when either there are no more records to update or when n reaches 100,000. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really understanding the WHERE criteria. Why must n increment? Edit question to show sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 1):

VBA procedure could have code like:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, lngCnt As Long
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM a WHERE pnsi Is Null;")
For lngCnt = 1 to 100000
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        rs.Edit
        rs!pnsi = lngCnt
        rs.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```